# Mocking: wrapping method and receiving args at call time

Tags: python, testing, mocking, patch

I wonder wether it's possible to patch a method somewhere deep inside code I don't own in a way that allows me to receive the args the method will receive right before or after that method is called without having an actual reference to the object on which the method is being called.

I want to be able to do something like

```
def wrapping(method, *args, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    rv = method(*args, **kwargs)
    # more stuff
    return rv


with mock.patch('path.to.The.method', wraps=wrapping):
    code_that_eventually_calls_the_method()
```

and then I get dropped into wrapping when the method is eventually called, but I can call the mocked method without having a reference to its object beforehand in the testcode. Is this achievable?

Comment: Maybe you are looking to [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) feature.

Comment: while side_effect gives me the args at call time, it looks like it blocks the actual function call, no?

Comment: You are trying to decorate a method and use it as wrapper of mock? Why you don't you just define the `return_value` to return you want?

Comment: Because I don't know what the method will return and I want the method to still execute normally. I'm not doing this inside a unit test, but want to change the behavior of some production code to inspect what is happening.